# Conditional validation not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Using a gem [for validating date overlap](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap), the attempt is to verify against existing records whether the new records overlaps for non-cancelled records. The class has attribute `cancelled` as boolean, default: false.

It appears the following syntax is erroneous as the application rollsback when hitting and existing cancelled object.

```
validates :start_time, :end_time, :overlap => {:scope => "instructor_id", :exclude_edges => ["start_time", "end_time"]}, if: -> {cancelled == false || require_validation}
```

what is the proper way to do this under rails 4.2 ?

*Update*

following the gem's conventions

```
validates :start_time, :end_time, :overlap => {:query_options => {:cancelled => nil}, :scope => "instructor_id", :exclude_edges => ["start_time", "end_time"]}
scope :cancelled, -> { where(:cancelled => false) }
```

does not fire either.

Comment: Shouldn't that lambda get the object as a parameter? `if: ->(obj) { obj.cancelled == false ...}`

Comment: attempted that unsuccessfully.  I may be off course, not applying the gem's suggested approach to scopes...